# CI/CD for ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API in AWS CodePipeline for AWS Lambda

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

This has surprisingly been a struggle for me to get the CI/CD pipeline working for a simple ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project.

So basically it's a simple ASP.NET Core Web API that I am deploying to AWS Lambda. I am using AWS CodePipeline and trying to keep the configuration as simple as I can without the use of any bash/ps scripts.

My pipeline has 3 stages: Source (AWS CodeCommit), Build (AWS CodeBuild) and Deploy (AWS CloudFormation). The source and build steps are working fine and as expected. The deploy stage is divided into two action groups: The first group has one action that creates a deploy stack and the second group also has one action that executes the stack created by the first group.

All is working fine but I am struggling to get different environments (dev/live) working. Below is my CloudFormation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.
Parameters:
  BuildBucketName:
    Type: String
  BuildObjectKey:
    Type: String
Conditions: {}
Resources:
  TatSatGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1
    Properties:
      StageName: Dev

  TatSatApiFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: TatSat.API::TatSat.API.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync
      Runtime: dotnetcore3.1
      AutoPublishAlias: Dev
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Ref BuildBucketName
        Key: !Ref BuildObjectKey
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 30
      Role:
      Policies:
      - AWSLambda_FullAccess
      Events:
        ProxyResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: "/{proxy+}"
            Method: ANY
            RestApiId: !Ref TatSatGatewayApi
        RootResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: "/"
            Method: ANY
            RestApiId: !Ref TatSatGatewayApi

Outputs:
  ApiURL:
    Description: API endpoint URL for Dev environment
    Value:
      Fn::Sub: https://${TatSatGatewayApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Dev/
```

I am just not sure how to get different environments injected in this template and then, how to push my changes only to a specific environment. I also tried creating alias and versions for lambda explicitly but then I got an error while the stack was being executed and it was something like "The resource already exists in stack".

Can anyone help? I am relatively new to all this but I would prefer not to use any framework like Serverless and keep my solution AWS specific, especially around CloudFormation only without any scripts (if that's possible). Would really appreciate if someone can provide a solution within the current scheme of things.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, I'm assuming the value of Fn can be changed to point to a specific environment (/Dev, /Prod) ? The value of ${AWS::Region} is in the appsettings.Development.json file, you can add there an entry for the environment then used that variable in serverless.template. Haven't tried it though, I've been trying to set up our project to make things like this easier to manage.

Comment: @MarlonAllanSupetran I ended up dividing the 'Deploy' stage into an Action Group with 5 actions, each having one of these changesets: Create-Dev-Changeset, Execute-Dev-Changeset, Review Changes, Create-Prod-Changeset and Execute-Prod-Changeset. This isn't perfect but it fulfilled my requirements. For Prod and Dev changesets, I have separate yaml template files in my project root, each having their own set of environment variables which get overridden in stage settings.